# UIGestureRecognizer working on parent class but not on subclass

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

So I'm working on an app at work where a majority of the code written has been written by other people.  So I have a class called `BaseDetailViewController` and another class which subclasses `BaseDetailViewController` called `ProductViewController`. I have a pinch recognizer on `ProductViewController` and there is a pinch recognizer on it's parent `BaseDetailViewController`.  It seems like the recognizer on the parent seems to be overriding the recognizer on `ProductViewController`.  When I comment out the one on the parent then the recognizer on the child works just fine.

I tried using:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    return TRUE;

}
```

with proper delegation to see if that helped but the recognizer on `BaseDetailViewController` seems to take the bacon every time.

What do I need to do to get the one on `ProductViewController` firing?

Comment: Down-vote with no comment?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you are trying to have two Pinch gesture recognizers on the same view. When you are adding pinch gesture recognizer in `ProductViewController`, try to invalidate pinch gesture recognizer in `BaseDetailViewController`. It should solve the problem.